# Stata Generate New Variable List By Multiplying Var Lists

Tags: stata

I have a balanced panel with a set of dummies for 'countries' and observations for several years. I want to generate a new set of variables that assigns a number in the sequence 1:n for each year observation of country i, and 0 for any other observation that is not from country i.

As an example, suppose I have two countries and two years. Below on the left is an example of my database. I want a new set of variables as shown on the right:

```
*Example of Database             Example of Desired Output
*country1 country2  year         output1  output2
*   1        0        1             1        0
*   1        0        2             2        0
*   0        1        1             0        1
*   0        1        2             0        2
```

How can I get the desired output? Intuitively I need to multiply 'country*' by 'year' to get 'output*', but I have been unable to make it work in Stata.

Below is what I tried.

```
gen output = year * country
* country is ambiguous

gen output = year * country*
* invalid syntax

foreach var in country*{
gen output_`var' = year * `var'
}
* invalid name
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post in an attempt to make this clearer.

Comment: The new variables can be used introduce a country-specific linear time trend in a OLS regression.

Answer (score 0):

Your last attempt almost solved it. The issue with your attempt is that you need to tell Stata that you are passing a `varlist` for you to be able to use the wildcards `*` and `?`. To be able to use a wildcard in `foreach`, do this:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte(country1 country2 year)
1 0 1
1 0 2
0 1 1
0 1 2
end

foreach var of varlist country* {
    gen `var'_year = year * `var'
}
```

The full name `country1`, `country2` etc. is stored in `` `var' `` so I took the freedom to update the name of the result variables to `country1_year`, `country2_year` etc. rather than  `output_country1`, `output_country2` etc.

Note that this solution will only work if the `country*` vars only have the values `1` and `0`, no observation has a missing value in any variable `country*` and no observation have the value `1` in more than one variable `country*`.